DropDown in flutter
How can I increase the height of the closed dropdown text area in Flutter (highlighted in red in the image)? I tried increasing the contentPadding vertical value to 40, but it only increases the overall height of the dropdown box, not just the text area. I also attempted to set the height in style and hint, but nothing seems to work to adjust the visible text area of the closed dropdown.
DropdownButtonFormField<ParkingModel>(
    isExpanded: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      errorStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      isDense: false,
      filled: true,
      fillColor: themeChange.getThem() ? AppThemData.grey10 : AppThemData.grey03,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40, horizontal: 10),
      prefixIcon: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icon/ic_car_image.svg", height: 24, width: 24),
      ),
      disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12), topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: themeChange.getThem() ? AppThemData.grey09 : AppThemData.grey04, width: 1),
      ),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12), topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: themeChange.getThem() ? AppThemData.primary06 : AppThemData.primary06, width: 1),
      ),
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12), topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: themeChange.getThem() ? AppThemData.grey09 : AppThemData.grey04, width: 1),
      ),
      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12), topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: themeChange.getThem() ? AppThemData.grey09 : AppThemData.grey04, width: 1),
      ),
      border: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12), topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: themeChange.getThem() ? AppThemData.grey09 : AppThemData.grey04, width: 1),
      ),
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          color: themeChange.getThem() ? AppThemData.grey06 : AppThemData.grey06,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontFamily: AppThemData.medium),
    ),
    value: controller.selectedParkingModel.value.id == null ? null : controller.selectedParkingModel.value,
    onChanged: (value) {
      controller.selectedParkingModel.value = value!;
      controller.update();
    },
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        color: themeChange.getThem() ? AppThemData.grey02 : AppThemData.grey08,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontFamily: AppThemData.medium),
    hint: Text(
      "Select Your Parking".tr,
      style: TextStyle(color: themeChange.getThem() ? AppThemData.grey07 : AppThemData.grey07),
    ),
    items: controller.parkingList.map((item) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<ParkingModel>(
        value: item,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 3),
            child: Text(item.name.toString(), style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
            ))),

      );
    }).toList()),

Image_
the text is displaying in the closed dropdown

Try wraping your DropdownButtonFormField with a SizedBox or Container and use the height property and adjust as per your need like below:


SizedBox(
  height: 80, // Set desired height
  child: DropdownButtonFormField<ParkingModel>(
    isExpanded: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, // Keep content padding minimal
      // Other decoration properties...
    ),
    // Other DropdownButtonFormField properties...
  ),
)



